# Prototype $ and $$ with special characters

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Is there anyway by which i can use the $ or $$ utility selectors with arguments containing special characters?

```
<div id="my example">

$('my example')

<div class="item1\item2">

$$('div.item1\item2')
```

I've tried using the standard escape sequence \ but am having no luck.

Comment: What special characters? You should avoid using special characters in your class and id names.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you mean `item2 that is a child of item1`?

Comment: sorry missed the code tags and it hid my div tags.
Darin: yes ideally we wouldn't have the special characters but its an unfortunate side effect of the data we're running against. The special characters we're interested in are space and \

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments to those functions can contain `id`s of elements. As the spec [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name):

> **ID** and **NAME** tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters,
>   digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and
>   periods (".").

This implies that special characters within `id`s are not allowed.

Comment: Have just run the source through the W3c validator:
This attribute can not take a space-separated list of words as a value, but only one word ("token"). This may also be caused by the use of a space for the value of an attribute which does not permit it
Well i guess that explains that one then